# See if value of identity column is less than some number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to see if the value of an identity column is less than 1.

```
IF (SELECT PKIdent FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE PKIdent < 1)
PRINT 'Its less than one'
```

Comment: The value from which row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you can do this:

```
IF ((SELECT min(PKIdent) FROM dbo.MyTable) < 1)
    PRINT 'Its less than one'
```

or

```
IF exists (SELECT PKIdent FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE PKIdent < 1)
    PRINT 'Its less than one'
```